# Check update periodically using postdelayed

Tags: android, multithreading, android-handler

In my app (as long as it is open) I want to sync my data with my server.

My strategy is the following :

```
//create the handler on which we will use postdelayed
Handler handler = new Handler();

//create the first runnable.
//Will this run on UI thread at this stage ? as it is being called from the handler ?
Runnable runnable1 = new Runnable()
{       
  public void run()
   {
     Thread t = new Thread(runnable2);
   }
};

//create the second runnable.
//This is for sure being called from a thread, so it will not run on UI thread ? NO ?
Runnable runnable2 = new Runnable()
{       
  public void run()
   {
     //connect to internet
//make the check periodical
handler.postdelayed(runnable1, 1000);
   }
};

//call the postdelayed.
handler.postdelayed(runnable1, 1000);
```

In case I want the handler to stop its runnable task once the application is closed. What shall I do incase I have several activities and I do not know where is the user when he/clicks the home button. Should I include a check in all onDestroys() ?

Comment: your assumptions are both correct. runnable1 runs on the ui thread, runnable2 runs in the thread you created. this is not periodical, however, as it runs only once.

Comment: @njzk2 i updated my question for the periodical. I also added a new question at the end. have a look.

Comment: any postDelayed after the destruction of the activity should silently fail, i think

Comment: I dont think so, as long as removeCallbacks(runnable1) is not called, it shall go on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you're second Runnable will be ran on a new thread not the UI thread.

When you do `new Handler();` this creates a handle to the current thread, if this code was in `onCreate` that thread would be the UI thread.

Therefore when you do `handler.post` it will post onto the UI thread (runnable1) , but when you start runnable2 you are explicitly creating a new thread to run this on.

It might not be the right strategy to create a new thread every 1 second (`postDelayed ..1000`) perhaps keep a reference to another background thread and post it a message every second to do something new.

---

To stop your repeated runnables you need to call `removeCallbacks(runnable1)` in `onPause` of any Activity (that I assume called `postDelayed` in `onCreate`)

Comment: I am planning of doing it every 30 seconds. I didnt quite get the "perhaps keep a reference to another background thread and post it a message every second to do something new." Can you explain further please... maybe an example ? I also added a new question inside my edited question. have a look.

Comment: Give your solution a go first, if you find it slow then I would change to having one thread with messages.

Comment: actually, I am planning on starting the handler inside the splash activity (which has a lifespan of 3 seconds, and will definitely be destroyed).. cancelling the handler there makes having a repetative handler (periodic postdelayed) pointless.. Moreover, I do not know in which activity the user might be when he/she presses the back/home

Comment: Just go with an `IntentService` and use a postDelayed to post new Intents to it every 30 seconds, that will clear everything up for you and you only need to cancel your postDelayed and your done. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Comment: "you only need to cancel your postDelayed and your done" what do you mean ? don't you still you need to cancel the postDelayed to avoid repetition (even tho the intentService is cancelled).

Comment: Your not going to get around having to have one "poster" for each Activity. So make sure you create it any onCreate and Cancel it any onPause.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37661/discussion-between-tony9099-and-blundell)